# Passing a $_SESSION using <a href> outside php tags

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working with PHP and in this instance I want to pass `$_SESSION` which I've already assigned with my `currentUser` object. This works fine.

I've used the header function to pass variables between pages such as `header('Location: example.php?uID='.$uID)` and then using **GET** to receive this value.

However, instead of using a header to automatically redirect, I want to use a `href` so that the user has to click on a link, which then initiates the redirect. 
The problem is that I use the anchor (`<a>`) inside the PHP tags and I can't pass variables using it inside the **HTML** tags.

I'd be very grateful for the solution and happy to elaborate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way :

```
//assuming that the user id is stored in the 'uID' field of $_SESSION
<a href="<?php echo 'exemple.php?uID='.$_SESSION['uID']; ?>">Redirect me !</a>
```